# onTouchEvent in TabActivity don't react on anything

Tags: android, tabactivity, touch-event

I have TabActivity:

```
public class timetable extends TabActivity  
{
...
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

but anything not happend when I move my finger on screen (push, fling, ..)
Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Toast.makeText(this, "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

put in

```
android.util.Log("TabActivity", "motion event type="+(event.getAction() & MotionEvent. ACTION_MASK)
```

Then you should see various events for touch down (0), move (2) and touch up (1). 
Take a look at Android log to see events (filter on TabActivity).

**Edited:**

I was not paying attention. TabActivity contains child Views which consume touch events. You should place your code inside child Views.

Comment: there are nothing in the log.
I tried to add Log.v(...) in oncreate() and in other places - and it worked.
But there are no messages like "motion event type=".

Comment: I think it's about TabActivity, becouse there are few questions like mine here.